# React Navigation 5, block back navigation after login

Tags: reactjs, react-native, back, react-navigation-v5

I am using React Navigation 5 in a project, and I'm having trouble trying to block a user from navigating back after a certain point.

The app uses a nested navigation structure similar to this:

```
ROOT (STACK)
|-- LoginScreens (STACK - options={{ gestureEnabled: false }} )
|   |-- Login (SCREEN) -> when successful navigate to "Home"
|   +-- Register (SCREEN) -> after registration, navigate to "Login"
|
+-- Home (TABS - options={{ gestureEnabled: false }} )
    |-- BlahBlah (SCREEN)
    |-- MyProfile (SCREEN)
    +-- Dashboard (TABS)
        |-- AllTasks (SCREEN)
        +-- SomethingElse (SCREEN)
```

After a successful user login, the user is sent to the `Home` screen and should not be able to navigate back to the `LoginScreens` screen.

I have tried to use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method on `Home`, as well as the `useFocusEffect` hook, with the following:

- Placing a callback to React Native's `BackHandler`, returning true from the handler works (true means back action has been handled, no further back handlers will be called), but it will also block any back navigation within the screens in `Home` (e.g. I cannot navigate back from Dashboard to MyProfile).
- Using `navigation.reset({ index: 1, routes: [{ name: "Home" }] })`. Without `index: 1` the navigation just goes back to ROOT's initialRoute (in this case, `LoginScreens`). With `index: 1`, a `Maximum update depth exceeded` error is thrown.
- Instead navigating directly to `Home`, I have tried using a `navigation.reset()` (note: no params, clears the entire navigation history), and after that navigate to the `Home` screen. This doesn't achieve the desired effect since the current route (ROOT's initialRoute, in this case: `LoginScreens`) is still pushed on the navigation history before navigating to `Home`.
- Combining navigation and reset calls in different ways, I have only managed to get JS angry and throw errors and exceptions at me.

Aaaaand... I have ran out of ideas. Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: Try a "replace" action after successful login to redirect current route instead of push a new route? If user hits back then they navigate to the route they were on *before* they navigated to the login route. What specific navigation package are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version of React Navigation 5, which is 5.0.5. Not sure if that's what you asked.

Using `navigation.replace("Home")` results in an error, `The action 'REPLACE' with payload '{"name":"Home"}' was not handled by any navigator.`, although there definitely is a route `Home` in the `ROOT` stack navigator...

Comment: I'm unfortunately not very familiar with `react-navigation`. Perhaps this [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#replace) helps.

Comment: It didn't actually help, I have called the method as per the docs, and it seems it fails. Not sure what's the reason though... anyway, I have managed to workaround this, I will post the solution shortly.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: @mohwarf Yes, please see the answer marked as solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I had posted this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60307042/12186963

However, eventually, I ended up not using it due to some serious jank issues I had with conditional rendering:
When a`Navigator` / `Screen` mounts, a lot of stuff happens, multiple screens might get instantiated (especially if you're using tabbed navigators without lazy mount), nested `<Navigator />`s might mount, `react-navigation` has to re-evaluate it's state, and much, much more.
The app does not have a choice but hold on until the entire route tree mounts before rendering it, which can cause blank flashes between mounts. On lower-end devices, the blank screen can persist for longer times than a user would tolerate.

The better alternative solution that I have found involves the imperative call to `NavigationContainer.resetRoot` method. By attaching a `ref` to the `NavigationContainer`, calling `resetRoot` will always act on the root navigation state.
`resetRoot` also allows to specify a new navigation state, which can be useful to change the currently active route.
The implementation is as follows:

`libs/root-navigation.js`

```js
import React from "react";

// This is the ref to attach to the NavigationContainer instance
export const ref = React.createRef();


/**
 * Resets the root navigation state, and changes the active route to the one specified
 * @param {string} name The name of the route to navigate to after the reset
 * @param {object|undefined} params Additional navigation params to pass to the route
 */
export function navigate(name, params) {
    try {
        ref.current.resetRoot({ index: 0, routes: [{ name, params }] });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Failed to reset the root navigation state. Make sure you have correctly attached the ref to the <NavigationContainer /> component.\nOriginal error:", e);
    }
}
```

`App.js`(or wherever you render your`<NavigationContainer />` component:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import * as RootNavigation from "./libs/root-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import LoginScreen from "./screens/Login";
import RegisterScreen from "./screens/Register";
import DashboardScreen from "./screens/Dashboard";
import AccountScreen from "./screens/Account";

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();
const AuthenticationStack = createStackNavigator();
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

function AuthenticationScreens() {
    return <AuthenticationStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
        <AuthenticationStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <AuthenticationStack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
    </AuthenticationStack.Navigator>;
}

function HomeScreens() {
    return <HomeStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Dashboard">
        <HomeStack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardScreen} />
        <HomeStack.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>;
}

export default function MyApp() {
    // ... your awesome code :)
    return <NavigationContainer ref={RootNavigation.ref}>
        <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Authentication">
            <RootStack.Screen name="Authentication" component={AuthenticationScreens} />
            <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreens} />
        </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>;
}
```

Then, in some other place in your app, you can always import the `navigate()` function from the `root-navigation.js` file, and use that to reset the root stack:

```
import { Pressable, Text, View } from "react-native";
import * as RootNavigation from "./libs/root-navigation";
import * as ServerAPI from "./server-api";

function LoginScreen() {
    const email = "hello@world.com";
    const password = "P@$sw0rD!";

    const onLoginPress = () => {
        ServerAPI.login(username, password).then(({ success, user })=>{
            if (success === true) {
                // Here we reset the root navigation state, and navigate to the "Home" screen
                RootNavigation.navigate("Home", { user });
            } else {
                alert("Wrong email or password...");
            }
        });
    }

    return <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Pressable onPress={onLoginPress}>
            <Text>Login now!</Text>
        </Pressable>
    </View>;
}
```

I much more prefer this solution rather than my initial one. It also works with `react-navigation@6.x`.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that React Navigation's docs tried to cover this use case with this guide:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

The example there is very tricky, already introduces state management libraries, reducers, React hooks, and whatever else that doesn't really help. However, the summary of that guide is: `Conditionally render routes`.

Unlinke React Navigation 4 and previous versions, in React Navigation 5 you can conditionally render routes. In doing so you effectively rule out any possibilities of navigation to an inexistent route. Below, there is a very short example of how you can do it with a simple state variable. Keep in mind however that this example only takes into account a navigator with one route rendered at a time. If you have more routes that are rendered other than the ones in this example, you may need to adjust the `RootStack.Navigator`'s props (`initialRouteName` for example), or explicitly navigate to a specific route.

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import LoginNav from "./screens/LoginNav";
import HomeScreens from "./screens/HomeScreens";

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

export default class MyApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = { isLoggedIn: false };
    }

    setIsLoggedIn = (isLoggedIn)=>{ this.setState({ isLoggedIn }); }

    render = () => {
        // Using an arrow function to allow to pass setIsLoggedIn to LoginNav
        // Pass setIsLoggedIn from the props of LoginNav to the screens it contains
        // then from the screens call this function with a true/false param
        const LoginScreens = (props)=> <LoginNav {...props} setIsLoggedIn={this.setIsLoggedIn} />

        return <NavigationContainer style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <RootStack.Navigator>
                {(this.state.isLoggedIn === false)
                    // If not logged in, the user will be shown this route
                    ? <RootStack.Screen name="LoginScreens" component={LoginScreens} />
                    // When logged in, the user will be shown this route
                    : <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreens} />
                }
            </RootStack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>;
    }
}
```

In this example, call `(this.)` `props.setIsLoggedIn(true)` to render the `Home` route, or call with a `false` param to return to the `LoginScreens` route.

Hopefully this example is easier to understand than the one in the docs.

Comment: This is not ideal solution IMO, as stack will still be there it would just be that the route will not be available. All the solution on internet about using reset don't work in v5

Comment: I know it's not a proper solution, but it's the only one available. Besides, in an authentication flow, you should not allow random navigation back-and-forth between authentication steps and main application. So after authentication you can conditionally render routes, and in the newly rendered route (in the onFocus event) have a reset that restores a correct navigation stack.

Comment: This is not ideally, Probably use redux instead for global state purpose.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I have to admit, its was not easy to find the new reset method's syntax for v5, man... ReactNavigation docs really need an in site search functionality.

Anyway, [reset method](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset) can be used, and worked perfectly for me.

It looks something like:

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'Home',
        params: { user: 'jane' },
      },
    ],
  })
);
```

I made a helper function which I am using in multiple places in my app, that looks like:

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const resetStackAndNavigate = (navigation, path) => {
  navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.reset({ index: 0, routes: [{ name: path }] }));
};
```

Comment: When using multiple nested navigators, reset will not work correctly unless you set the proper object tree representing the specified navigator. If not, reset will act on the parent-most navigator only, reset index to 0, try to find that route and fail. So, it will fall back to the initialRoute or the first route in the navigation tree, depending on navigator's props. I tried using reset in various ways with nested navigators, didn't work for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way for react-navigation v5:

I've created a CustomDrawerContent-Component to be able to handle each press on an item:

*(Note: Ignore `header` and `footer` property, it's only an adjustment for my drawer.)*

```
...
import {
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
...

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  const {
    state: {routes, index},
    descriptors,
    navigation,
    header,
    footer,
  } = props;
  return (
    <>
      {header}
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        {routes.map((route, i) => {
          const focused = i === index;
          const {title, drawerLabel, drawerIcon} = descriptors[
            route.key
          ].options;

          return (
            <DrawerItem
              key={route.key}
              label={
                drawerLabel !== undefined
                  ? drawerLabel
                  : title !== undefined
                  ? title
                  : route.name
              }
              icon={drawerIcon}
              focused={focused}
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.dispatch(
                  CommonActions.reset({index: i, routes: [{name: route.name}]}),
                  // NOTICE: Removes the routes.<name>.state of the Stack to discard
                  // navigation-Position if coming back to it via Drawer-Menu.
                  // If this Stack-State in seeded later on, you can adjust it here needed
                );
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
      {footer}
    </>
  );
}

function MainDrawer(props) {
  const {
    screen,
    screen: {initialRoute},
    navigatorProps,
    header,
    footer,
    hideDrawerItems,
  } = props;
  return (
    <Navigator
      initialRouteName={initialRoute}
      {...navigatorProps}
      drawerContent={(drawerProps) => (
        <CustomDrawerContent {...drawerProps} header={header} footer={footer} />
      )}>
      {createMenuEntries(screen, hideDrawerItems)} // that's  only an custom implementation of mine to create <Screen>-Entries. Feel free to replace it with your own
    </Navigator>
  );
}

export default MainDrawer;
```

The Magic at least is here:

```
{routes.map((route, i) => {
...
onPress => navigation.dispatch => CommonActions.reset({index: ⇒⇒ i ⇐⇐
```

While we map over each route, we use the current index and the route-name (of the drawer-item itself) to reset it's route-state, if we tapped it.

This works perfectly fine for my purposes, because even if you are in `News ⇒ News Detail"`and open the Drawer and click again on `News`, you are piped to the first Screen of your `News-Stack`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like the accepted solution, but the other way to do this is to use React Context.

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext();

const setIsLoggedIn = (isLoggedIn) => {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn }); 
}
```

and then wrap your entire navigator:

```
 <AuthContext.Provider value={setIsLoggedIn}>
     <RootStackNavigator>
        // your screens, etc.
     </RootStackNavigator>
 </AuthContext.Provider>
```

then in your screen, you can use:

```
 const { setIsLoggedIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
```

and call it when you want.

See this guide: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/